# Pure CSS - Fade in delay only (no fade out)

Tags: html, css

Once a `div` is clicked, I would like to toggle fade the content of a div and once more when the element is clicked again. Now, the content should only have a fade in delay - and thus not when fading out.

I already have the vanilla JavaScript to add and remove the respective classes, but I want the animations to be done with CSS. Thus, how should this be done only using pure CSS?

Comment: show us your code and have you done

Comment: @TemaniAfif Let's say it's just a parent `div` with some child paragraph in it, the content doesn't really matter here.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Supply us with what you have tried and also a working example like a snippet or a fiddle.

Comment: @Granny I'm just looking for the CSS property that would allow me to do this easily, but apparently there is none and I'll have to use a workaround.

Comment: @Levano I know what you are looking for but my comment still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to fade in/out as you want.

```
.fade-in {
    /* the "1s" is the duration of the animation.
    The "0.25s" is the delay before the animation starts. */
    transition: color 1s linear 0.25s;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.fade-out {
    transition: color 1s;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Seems like I'll have to go with this solution and use a generic class for my delays. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css transitions read about them here [CSS Transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).  I would go with opacity so set your divs content to have an opacity of 0 then when the class is added give it an opacity of 1 and then you can set the duration in the transition property like so:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener("click", function(){
 this.classList.toggle("content-shown");
});
```

```css
div{
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
p{
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
div.content-shown p{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Here is the divs content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without JavaScript it is possible with a `<input type="checkbox">` and a connected `<label>`. You should just write CSS for the initial state and the "clicked" state.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+label {
  color: transparent;
  transition: 500ms 500ms;
}

label {
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: none;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle">Toggle me</label>
```

Comment: This doesn't address OP's question: how to make the content fade in/out. He's not asking how to change colors.

Comment: @EKW This way every possible CSS change could be toggle easily.